# Android ClassNotFoundException after including GaugeView library

Tags: java, android, mobile

I am trying to use the Gauge View from [github](https://github.com/CodeAndMagic/GaugeView)
The sample application that is given with the library works perfect !

But when i try to include the library into the project (properties > buildpath > projects > (add library project)), put the view in my layout and try to get a reference to the view in code it throws `ClassNotFoundException`

The following is the error that i get through logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(  542): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(  542): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.guagetest/com.example.guagetest.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class org.codeandmagic.android.gauge.GaugeView
E/AndroidRuntime(  542):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
E/AndroidRuntime(  542):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
E/AndroidRuntime(  542):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
E/AndroidRuntime(  542):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
E/AndroidRuntime(  542):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(  542):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(  542):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
E/AndroidRuntime(  542):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  542):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(  542):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
E/AndroidRuntime(  542):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
E/AndroidRuntime(  542):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  542): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class org.codeandmagic.android.gauge.GaugeView
E/AndroidRuntime(  542):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)
E/AndroidRuntime(  542):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
E/AndroidRuntime(  542):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
E/AndroidRuntime(  542):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
E/AndroidRuntime(  542):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
E/AndroidRuntime(  542):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
E/AndroidRuntime(  542):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
E/AndroidRuntime(  542):    at com.example.guagetest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
E/AndroidRuntime(  542):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
E/AndroidRuntime(  542):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
E/AndroidRuntime(  542):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
E/AndroidRuntime(  542):    ... 11 more
E/AndroidRuntime(  542): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codeandmagic.android.gauge.GaugeView
E/AndroidRuntime(  542):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
E/AndroidRuntime(  542):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
E/AndroidRuntime(  542):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
E/AndroidRuntime(  542):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
E/AndroidRuntime(  542):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
E/AndroidRuntime(  542):    ... 21 more
W/ActivityManager(   77):   Force finishing activity com.example.guagetest/.MainActivity
```

I have no idea why it is not able to find the class. Somebody please help.
Is there anything special that is done in the sample application that i need to do to get it to work ?

the following is my layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <org.codeandmagic.android.gauge.GaugeView
     android:id="@+id/gauge_view1"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="0dp"
     android:layout_weight="1" />


</LinearLayout>
```

This is my activity:

```
package com.example.guagetest;

import org.codeandmagic.android.gauge.GaugeView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private GaugeView gauge;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        gauge = (GaugeView) findViewById(R.id.gauge_view1);
        gauge.setTargetValue(10);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: you added libs in android-logging-log4j-1.0.3.jar and log4j-1.2.16.jar ?

Comment: my completed worked this application.

Comment: yes i did include the jars android-logging-log4j-1.0.3.jar and log4j-1.2.16.jar into the project. Still no luck with my new app.. i don't know what i'm doing different from the demo app on github.

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime(  542):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251) on click and put java code(line)

Comment: i'm really sorry i did not understand that. Cloud you please elaborate a little bit more on your previous comment.

Comment: not wrong (.java) and (.xml) your file. i checked

Comment: could you please tell me how to set up and include this library into my project to be able to use the view ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29342/discussion-between-anilmetatagg-and-abhishek-s)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't post any code, but the fact that your spelling of a particular word is inconsistent even in your post suggests that you need to check how you're spelling things in your code.  Look at these two words carefully:

```
String correct = "gauge";
String wrongWrongWrong = "guage";
```

Comment: The spelling was my mistake :( . But it doesn't seem to be the problem as its consistent in the rest of the code. Updated question with my layout and activity.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private GaugeView mGaugeView1;
    private GaugeView mGaugeView2;
    private final Random RAND = new Random();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mGaugeView1 = (GaugeView) findViewById(R.id.gauge_view1);
        mGaugeView2 = (GaugeView) findViewById(R.id.gauge_view2);
        mTimer.start();
    }

    private final CountDownTimer mTimer = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(final long millisUntilFinished) {
            mGaugeView1.setTargetValue(RAND.nextInt(101));
            mGaugeView2.setTargetValue(RAND.nextInt(101));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {}
    };
}
```

**Edit**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:gauge="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/org.codeandmagic.android.gauge.samples"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:padding="20dp" >

   <org.codeandmagic.android.gauge.GaugeView
        android:id="@+id/gauge_view1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <org.codeandmagic.android.gauge.GaugeView
        android:id="@+id/gauge_view2"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        gauge:showOuterShadow="true"
        gauge:showOuterRim="false"
        gauge:showNeedle="false"
        gauge:showRanges="false"
        gauge:showText="true"
        gauge:textUnit="%" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: yes, i did run this first, this is the sample code on the github page right!? Like i said in my post this sample application works perfect ! but its when i try to integrate the view into a new application is when it gives me the error.

Answer (score 0):

Gauge that you are using have bugs and don't run fine on Kitkat and Lollipop. Also there is no Android Studio and gradle friendly library here.

This here is basically the same library you are using but forked from other developer and updated to work for new versions of android. Also you can use with Gradle and include easy in your project without any errors:

http://www.sule.io/?p=25

[image]

After you include library in your project add gaugelibrary to xml layout of your activity:

```
<io.sule.gaugelibrary.GaugeView
 android:id="@+id/gauge_view"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="#ffffff"
 gauge:showOuterShadow="false"
 gauge:showOuterRim="false"
 gauge:showInnerRim="false"
 gauge:needleWidth="0.010"
 gauge:needleHeight="0.40"
 gauge:scaleStartValue="0"
 gauge:scaleEndValue="100"
 />
```

This will show static gauge without needle. To instantiate needle with random animation you need to do that in activity class file. See how it's done here:

```
package io.sule.testapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import java.util.Random;

import io.sule.gaugelibrary.GaugeView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   private GaugeView mGaugeView;
   private final Random RAND = new Random();

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      mGaugeView = (GaugeView) findViewById(R.id.gauge_view);
      mTimer.start();
   }


   private final CountDownTimer mTimer = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

      @Override
      public void onTick(final long millisUntilFinished) {
         mGaugeView.setTargetValue(RAND.nextInt(101));
      }

      @Override
      public void onFinish() {}
   };
}
```

This will instantiate needle and make it animate moving to random values.